# laravel api patch method not reading request from controller/postman

Tags: php, laravel, api

We are working with our api using laravel. When we test our api, there is one method that not accepting any request even in postman. But if I write down the parameters in the url it accepts the method. Can someone know what is the problem with this one?

Method

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $studid = User::find($request->user_id);
        if(empty($studid))
            return response()->json([
                'code' => '03',
                'status' => 'Invalid Student ID'
            ], 403);
        if($studid->role != 4)
            return response()->json([
                'code' => '03',
                'status' => 'Invalid Student ID'
            ], 403);

        $parentid = User::find($studid->parent_id);

        $schattlog = new SchAttlog;

        $schattlog->user_id = $studid->id;
        $schattlog->school_id = $studid->school_id;
        $schattlog->log_type = $request->log_type;
        $schattlog->log_date = $request->log_date;
        $schattlog->log_timefrom = $request->log_timefrom;
        $schattlog->log_timeto = $request->log_timeto;
        $schattlog->status = 1;
        $schattlog->save();
     return response()->json([
            'code' => '01',
            'status' => 'Student Logged'
        ]);
    }
```

Postman response using form-data payload
[image]

Postman response when values put in the url directly
the url i put is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/inx/sal?user_id=10&log_type=in&log_date=2019-11-11&log_timefrom=500&log_timeto=500&school_id=1`
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past i ran also in that issue using patch in postman.

The solution is to use the `x-www-form-urlencode` tab instead of `form-data`

Comment: what is the difference of the two sir? And we got another problem theres no any data inserted when we test it to live server. is there something wrong with my controller?

Comment: `x-www-form-urlencode` is working for me. but when we put actual data from our rfid there is no data inserted. what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by actual data? So postman works but your F/E is not working? When you make a request to a patch make sure you include the header:  `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Postman will automatically apply it for you if you select this tab.

Comment: i mean the actual data from our rfid device is not storing in the database. but our api works. so there is nothing wrong with the api isnt it? should i use patch or post request? Which is the best?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Post is to create a new record, patch is to update. Both work fine and post will do also update but it's not right to mix them up that's why we have api standards :) Since you said that it's working locally but not  with your rfid i would check the headers of the requests, the error log, env file etc etc. If it works locally and not in production then something else is going wrong.

Comment: what do you think of the code of our api sir? theres nothing wrong about it right?

Comment: The code looks fine and should work fine. What is your production error? Just a small suggestion change the error codes. They must be unique so 03/04 so you know what went wrong.

Comment: i cant say the error because i am not the one whos incharge of the rfid but this is the api endpoint that is used in rfid. maybe we should change the method to post in order to work?

Comment: You can change it to post of course and it should work , like Patch should work. Since it is working in your local environment i would look further in what is different in production. Error logs will help you in that.

Comment: so there is no point in changing it to post sir, right? We use c# in the rfid but sad to say im not familiar with c# and im not the one who coded the rfid and connecting the api in it

Comment: Since your api is working in postman, it's working in general. the only thing you can do is inform the rfid people about it and work with them to see why it does not work with them.

Comment: ill post the error log when i get it from our other dev

Comment: Make sure to make a new question then, since it will be more c# related. hope i helped you!!!